# how to fetch data from API in react and search from the api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying to fetch this API dataset https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes in react. I want to allow the user to search from the API using the id. whenever the user clicks on the search button I want to change the color of the search button. after the user enters the id and clicks the search button I want to fetch the dataset and display it in a li list I want to display the id, quotes, and year. Here is the code that I have right now but it's not working.

````
import "mvp.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

function City() {
  const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes`).then((response) => {
      setAPIData(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearchInput(searchValue);
    if (searchInput !== "") {
      const filteredData = APIData.filter((item) => {
        return Object.values(item).join("").toLowerCase().includes(searchInput);
      });
      setFilteredResults(filteredData);
    } else {
      setFilteredResults(APIData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <Input
        style={{ backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue" }}
        icon="search"
        placeholder="Search for 2008, 2012 or 2013 "
        onChange={(e) => searchItems(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div itemsPerRow={3} style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        {searchInput.length > 1
          ? filteredResults.map((item) => {
              const { id, quote, year } = item;
              return (
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <h1>ID: {id}</h1>
                    <li>QUOTE: {quote}</li>
                    <li>YEAR: {year}</li>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })
          : APIData.map(() => {
              return <h1></h1>;
            })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return <City />;
}

```
`
````

Comment: How is it _"not working"_? Are there any errors reported in your browser console? FYI, there's absolutely no reason to wrap `searchQuotes` within `useSearchQuotes`

Comment: I don't think that API offers a _search_ function ~ https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/doc

Comment: How about this API https://api.nobelprize.org/2.1/laureates?_ga=2.41438754.1285935918.1666923968-1694059108.1666923968 @Phil

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited my code. Now I just want to add a button for searching and changing the color when clicked

Answer (score -1):

The api is not responding for single values
const URL = `https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes?s=${searchValue}`;

instead of supplying the value dynamically try once with manually providing the value

const URL = `https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes?s=1`;

and see in the console are you getting the value for the requested id.

```
 function handleInput(){
console.log("From onclick -" +search);
fetch(`https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes?id=1`)
.then((res)=>res.json())
.then((data)=>console.log(data));
```

}

I tried to get a single record, but failed.

Comment: I tried this and it is working but I want to use a search button and change the color whenever it is clicked. Would you help me out with that?

Comment: function City() {
  const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes`).then((response) => {
      setAPIData(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

Comment: const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearchInput(searchValue);
    if (searchInput !== "") {
      const filteredData = APIData.filter((item) => {
        return Object.values(item)
          .join("")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
      });
      setFilteredResults(filteredData);
    } else {
      setFilteredResults(APIData);
    }
  };return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <Input
        icon="search"
        placeholder="Search..."
        onChange={(e) => searchItems(e.target.value)}
      />

Comment: <div itemsPerRow={3} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        {searchInput.length > 1
          ? filteredResults.map((item) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <h1>ID: {item.id}</h1>
                    <li>QUOTE: {item.quote}</li>
                    <li>YEAR: {item.year}</li>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })
          : APIData.map((item) => {
              return <h1></h1>;
            })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );